# How can I yank the whole line without the "\n\r" at the end?

Tags: vim, vi

I know that `y$` can yank the string from the cursor's position to the end of line, but the `"\n\r"` is always included, is there any solution to do that without having the `"\n\r"` included?

Comment: as you wrote y$ does not yank line feeds, what about using "^y$"? go to the beginning of line then yank from this to end?

Comment: [Read the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_04.html#04.6)? [Pray the Google God for an answer](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Way-to-clear-line-without-removing-the-line-td4268076.html)? [Consider switching to something less nasty](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)?

Comment: I find that `yy` includes the end-of-line (EOL) character but that `y$` does not.  Are you editing a file that includes visible EOL characters?  If so, then perhaps you have the wrong setting for the `'fileformats'` option.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to move the cursor to the beginning of the line and yank from there to the end of the line:

```
0y$
^y$
```